# Is there a term for words that have a single meaning or are only used in a single context?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, nonce-words, uniquity, cranberry-morphemes

Certain words you hear in English are only ever heard in a single context. For example, *skirl* is used to describe [the sound a bagpipe makes](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=skirl&searchmode=none). Etymonline generously says the word is "rarely" heard outside that context, but I can't recall ever hearing it used for anything else. I imagine one could use it figuratively to describe another godawful high-pitched screech (sorry, bagpipe lovers), but there's no other bona fide usage for it.

What I want to know is stated in the title of the question: Is there a term for these one-off words? I'm sure there must be, but I can't think of what it might be.

**Edit:** Judging from some of the head-scratching comments I've received, there seems to be some confusion. Perhaps I did not make my meaning clear. I'm not looking for a word to describe the single instance of *skirl*. I'm asking about a class of words like *skirl*. I know there exist other examples of words that are only ever used in one context, but I can't think of any others at the moment.

Comment: What would be the point of having such a word to describe such obscurities?

Comment: @Arjun J Rao: If you're curious about that, perhaps you could ask it as an independent question.

Comment: The only other time I've seen *skirl* used is in the most excellent book, [*The Master of The Fallen Chairs* by Henry Porter](http://www.henry-porter.com/Books/The-Master-of-the-Fallen-Chairs.html) - it is supposed to be the first in a set called *The House of Skirl*, which is the name of the major house/household the book revolves around.

Comment: Additionally... Oi! Don't diss the bagpipes! :-p

Comment: @Orbling: Sorry. :) (If you're sensitive about the pipes, don't read what George MacDonald Fraser said about the sound they make.)

Comment: @Robusto: To each their own.  Though I do love good pipe music, but then I like most traditional music.  Such tastes are in the minority, regrettable, not quite as regrettable as *grime* music being in the ascendant mind.

Comment: Such a word would be so specific and limited in its use that it would be able to be used to describe itself.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: A platypus is a one-of-a-kind animal, yet it has a name.

Comment: @Arjun & Kosmonaut: We have the term 'onomatopoeia' to describe a small subset of words, why shouldn't there be a similar word to describe the subset that Robusto described?

Comment: Do we have a term for words that are used for different purposes?  'Homonym' described word that sound alike, (read/reed), but 'bow' is used to tie a ribbon, strike a note on a violin, act as the front-most part of a boat, or an act we do after a performance.  Are 'multinym' or 'polynym' real words?

Comment: If 'polynym' can be used to describe words with multiple meanings, may I suggest 'uninym' to describe Robusto's words?

Comment: I actually wasn't saying there couldn't be a word; I was only trying to make an amusing observation :)

Comment: @oosterwal: I hate to be a pedant—okay, I don't—but the correct form would be *mononym* then.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I think you have to break out the emoticons more freely then. Damned UTF-8 text, damned near useless for the wry and the ironic. :)

Comment: @Cerberus: I agree with 'mononym'.

Comment: 'polyseme' I think would be the appropriate term for a single word with multiple meanings.

Comment: Why is everyone avoiding the obvious term: 'unambiguous'?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's a "[stormy petrel](http://www.satiche.org.uk/satiche/sat-0342.htm)." The idea, as described on the linked page, is that (for example) you never (or, at least, rarely) find a *petrel* that's not *stormy*. Similarly, "all *shrift* is *short*," and lots of other examples. One of the ones there is in fact "every *skirl* is of *bagpipes*."

Comment: Bravo! Great link, too.

Comment: +1 However, note that now even the *stormy petrel* is not actually necessarily stormy anymore which implies that it is not even a *stormy petrel* anymore, since it can have, at least, two meanings (one is a bird and another a class of words). Similarly, for every instance of the other *petrels* I bet you will find a poem and a poet that used it without its *storm*, letting it imply its literal or metaphorical sense.

Comment: Nice idea, but *stormy petrel* is a really bad term for it, since *petrel* is the name of a family of birds, including the black-capped petrel (www.birdlife.org/datazone/speciesfactsheet.php?id=3911\), the snow petrel, and several others

Comment: @TimLymington: yeah, the author of that page mentions that "there is such a thing as a petrel which isn't stormy, but the term was a catchy one so it stuck."

Comment: Let me see -- "stormy petrel" is a *word*? Am I missing something here? I mean, if phrases are to be candidates, there sure must be any number of them.

Comment: A good fraction of that list's examples are bogus, though: they're just common **collocations**. Just because the cerebral cortex is the only cortex the author is aware of doesn't mean that all [cortices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortex) are cerebral. I'm not sure why he thinks "parlance" is an example, since it is reasonably common by itself. Nothing's special about "Maginot"; it's just a noun adjunct referring to [the French politician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Maginot).

Comment: i don't get the "zest" example at all. "zest" is used in all kinds of contexts.

Comment: Similarly "bestride", which COCA has pairing with "colossus" only 5 out of 18 times, and even those not as a fixed phrase.

Answer (score 13):

Closely related are [fossil words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_word), which have no meaning outside of a certain set phrase.  "Bated" survives only in "bated breath", for example.

Comment: Accessible via http://www.docstoc.com/docs/123195596/Fixed-Expressions-and-Idioms-in-English-A-Corpus-Based-Approach , Section 5.1.3 lists **cranberry collocations** which include either a **fossil word**, or a _loan word_ not used otherwise in English, together with other word/s. One group of cranberry collocations "contains lexemes which are unique to the FEI [fixed expression/s and/including idiom/s] but homographic with other independent items", such as _to boot_ (_boot_ only occurs _with this sense_ in this expression).

Comment: Hamlet thought he was dueling Laertes with *bated points*, but only his was ...

Answer (score 12):

There are several terms for closely related concepts:

- A [**nonce word**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word) is a word that somebody made up for a localized purpose. Apart from fossilized words, those nonce words that caught on are probably the major part of this group.
- A [**cranberry morpheme**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry_morpheme) is a morpheme that has no meaning on its own, and exists only as part of one or a small number of words. (It's named after the "cran" of "cranberry".) A [**fossil word**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_word) is similarly a word that is used only in a small number of phrases (but whose state is specifically due to the original meaning's obsolescence).
- A [***hapax legomenon***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapax_legomenon) (of a particular corpus) is a word that appears exactly once.

Answer (score 6):

There is no clear word or term that conveys words that have a single meaning or are only used in a single context. The nearest match is the word [*unequivocal*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unequivocal):

> having only one possible meaning or interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

In the first part of your question, you have asked if there is a term for words that have a single meaning. I think the answer is "monosemy" which refers to the fact of having only a single meaning.

According to [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/monosemy) it means:

> The property of having only one meaning.

Answer (score 2):

This conversation may have rather run its course a while ago... but a friend of mine (author Patrick Woodrow) and some of his friends had a game called 'Dependencies' which was about identifying exactly these kinds of words.  We've added to the list periodically over the years - it includes words such as 'shrift', mentioned above - as well as others like 'spick', 'champing', 'abetted', 'kibosh', 'betide', 'madding' etc.  No doubt a number of these would fall under the fossil words referred to above too. Best wishes, Ed

Comment: Thirty white horses on a red hill. First they champ, then they stamp, then they stand still.

Comment: Yeah, I read *The Hobbit* too.

Answer (score -3):

By analogy with prime numbers, this subset of words could be called "prime words", for they can only be described by one of them and its own definition. It would be a neat connection between words and numbers.