# why do we say scorching hot while scorching already means very hot?

Tags: expressions

Scorching means extremely hot. So why do we say scorching hot? Isn't it redundant to bring hot after scorching?

Comment: Blame that hydra-headed serpent — *tautology*!

Comment: So you don't confuse it with things that are [scorching cold](https://bakugan.wiki/wiki/Scorching_Cold) or [bitterly hot](https://www.capegazette.com/article/spice-your-life-dash-paprika/149468).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scorching is both **adjective** and **adverb**. If you use it before an adjective like hot it means you're using it as an adverb, which means very or extremely. As an adverb it means very hot. So it's not considered as redundant info.

Examples:

> Here in Houston, it was a **scorching** 93° today.
>
> It was a **scorching hot** day.
>
> The **scorching desert** heat

Comment: Shouldn't that be `scorchingly hot`?

Comment: Also, I'd suggest: "...it was *a* scorching 93˚ today."

Comment: @SLaks: No, here scorching is an adverb. So we don't add "ly" to end of it.

Comment: On what basis do you say this run-of-the-mill participle is sometimes (properly) an adverb?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, *scorching heat* (or *scorchingly hot*) appears at first glance to be redundant. Also, it is something of a [stormy petrel](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10614/is-there-a-term-for-words-that-have-a-single-meaning-or-are-only-used-in-a-single) (thank you again, Alex): You can't say something is scorchingly cold or scorchingly tepid.

Good writers might find a sharper way to express the heat, probably avoiding a cliché into the bargain. Still, in conversations and informal writing this kind of adjective (or adverb) is used simply as an intensifier. You'll agree, I'm sure, that *scorching* heat is many degrees more uncomfortable than *mild* heat. Is it as hot as *extreme* heat? I'm not sure. But both *extreme* and *scorching* heat refer to weather that is pretty damned hot.

In any case, something that is *scorched* is heated so as "to become dried out and lifeless" [Webster's] — so it has a particular meaning after all. There are all kinds of heat that do not cause things to become dried out and lifeless.

Comment: "avoiding a cliché into the bargain" -- that's either quite witty or quite unfortunate a way to phrase it.

Answer (score 2):

*Scorch*, as a verb, means to burn slightly or to cause discoloration due to heat.

As an adjective, *scorching* can be used to emphasize that the following noun causes burns or discoloration.  In that regard, "a scorching heat" implies that the heat causes burns or discoloration.  It is roughly synonymous with *burning*.