# Unitasker words like "crossbones"?

Tags: phrases, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a term for words that have a single meaning or are only used in a single context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10614/is-there-a-term-for-words-that-have-a-single-meaning-or-are-only-used-in-a-single)

I don't think I've ever heard the word "crossbones" outside of the phrase "skull and crossbones."  I'll call it a unitasker word — a word that is used within a single phrase the vast majority of the time.

Is there a more official term for a unitasker word?

Are there other examples?

Comment: They have been dubbed **stormy petrels**.  See this question: ["Is there a term for words that have a single meaning or are only used in a single context?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10614/is-there-a-term-for-words-that-have-a-single-meaning-or-are-only-used-in-a-single) Follow the link in the accepted answer for more examples.

Comment: Note, however, that the linked page isn't *entirely* accurate. Just for example, it lists "zest" as always being linked with "for life", but in fact "zest of lemon" is used fairly routinely in cooking.