# Can "shrugging" only be done with shoulders?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, collocation, objects

Please compare

> He shrugged.

and

> He shrugged his shoulders.

Is there anything else that can be shrugged, besides shoulders? To me it sounds like duplication when used in this way. I'm aware of constructs like "He shrugged it off." but that's not what I'm interested in, and it also implies the use of shoulders, doesn't it?

So why the need to specify the shoulders as an object?

[edit: I also find "he shrugged his eyebrows" but that's rather rare.]

Comment: Usually, the verb with eyebrows is: "knitted." I'm giving this question a +1 because it's a good one. In running text, I can imagine writing something like, "I don't know," he shrugged. It does seem slightly redundant to specify shoulder movement because shrugging only involves shoulders, just as "akimbo" only applies to arm position. Then there's the "Gallic Shrug": http://blip.tv/jeffrey-taylors-vlog/how-to-gallic-shrug-499784

Comment: @The Raven: *legs akimbo* is a phrase I have heard fairly often. I've not thought of it applying to arms

Comment: @Matt, @The Raven: [google ngrams confirms](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=arms+akimbo%2Clegs+akimbo&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) that *arms akimbo* is older and still much more common, but that *legs akimbo* is becoming less unusual, especially in BrE.

Comment: Interesting question. I've heard of a *mouth shrug*, the somewhat frowny lip-pursing business that frequently accompanies a shrug of the shoulderly variety. And if somebody pleasant but inconvenient (such as a cat or a lover) were sitting on my lap, I wouldn't have a problem shrugging them off.

Comment: How curious. "Legs akimbo" must be a UK-ism.

Comment: I suppose you could shrug *one* shoulder, as opposed to both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Browsing through [COHA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) and [Google Books](http://books.google.com/), I can’t find any body parts that can be shrugged apart from shoulders.  In any case, the intransitive use — *she shrugged* etc. — is certainly always understood as the shoulder-gesture — it is, as you say, essentially redundant.

So *shrugged* is very nearly a [stormy petrel](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10614/is-there-a-term-for-words-that-have-a-single-meaning-or-are-only-used-in-a-single).  The only other thing you can do with it (that I can think of or find in the dictionary) is to *shrug something off*.

(If anyone at a subscribed university or library is reading, by the way, the [OED online](http://www.oed.com) would be my best bet to look for other usages — their historical quotations will hopefully show how it came to be used this way.  Unfortunately I’m currently travelling and so without access.  Also, a clever COHA search would probably be able to automatically look there for instances of anything non-shouldery being shrugged, more thoroughly than I could browse.)

Comment: Is there any special differences between your answer and mine? except long explanation, actually.

Comment: That stormy petrel thing is bizarre. I have seen many petrels, but no stormy petrels yet, so to me that term could only refer to a subset of a small bird family:-) And @boob - in context I have to imagine you have blue feet:-)

Comment: @Jon: Um, yes my feet sometimes go Blue! :/

Comment: @Rory: Yes — whoever coined the term *stormy petrel* for this phenomenon clearly wasn’t a birdwatcher!  I quite like the term nonetheless.

Comment: @Boob: well, we both agree that the basic answer is “yes”, but beyond that our answers seem quite different to me!  You gave a nice ngrams search for comparative and historical data on the main usages; I took a different approach and went looking for minority uses, and pointed out the relevant *stormy petrel* concept.

Comment: @PLL: Ah, then let's fight to win.

Comment: I'll happily accept "stormy petrel" for "words that only exist in a single construction." Like "vim" in "vigor and vim."

Comment: the OED does have some other body part references such as a shrug of the hand **"And with my hand will give a shrug or two."** ~1653

Comment: @TheRaven: Surely you mean vim and emacs. (Anyway, it's [*vim and vigor*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vim+and+vigor%2C+vigor+and+vim&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvim%20and%20vigor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvigor%20and%20vim%3B%2Cc0).)

Answer (score 5):

### According to Google Ngram, men are ***shrugging their broad, heavy, great shoulders*** less and less.

But before that, let's see what men and women shrug most often according to Google Books.

For men I entered the expression *shrugged his* *. The asterisk symbol which follows will display the first word that comes after the pronoun *his*. Note that it is superfluous and counterproductive to search for "he shrugged his" because the possessive pronoun already tells us the subject is male and moreover you would ignore the innumerable instances where a proper noun or noun phrase would be used, for example "Daniel shrugged his", "Her husband shrugged his" etc.

[image]

For women I repeated the same operation

[image]

Interestingly, people tend to *shrug off* females i.e. **shrugged her off**. I went back to my first Ngram and repeated the experiment with [*shrugged him* *](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shrugged%20him%20*&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cshrugged%20him%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bshrugged%20him%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshrugged%20him%20away%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshrugged%20him%20aside%3B%2Cc0) The following results were: *shrugged him off*, *shrugged him away*, *shrugged him aside*

For the [feminine Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shrugged%20her%20shoulders%2C%20shrugged%20her%20pretty%20*%2C%20shrugged%20her%20thin%20*%2C%20shrugged%20her%20plump%20*%2C%20shrugged%20her%20white%20*&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20her%20shoulders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20her%20pretty%20shoulders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20her%20thin%20shoulders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20her%20plump%20shoulders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20her%20white%20shoulders%3B%2Cc0) I wondered if a woman might *shrug her pretty hips*, *finger*, *eyes* or *eyebrows*. I entered the terms: *shrugged her shoulders*, **shrugged her pretty ***, *shrugged her thin* *, *shrugged her plump* *, *shrugged her white* *

The results proved conclusively that ***shoulders*** is the only part of the human body associated with the verb, *shrug*.

In the following "masculine" [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shrugged%20his%20heavy%20*%2Cshrugged%20his%20great%20*%2Cshrugged%20his%20thin%20*%2Cshrugged%20his%20broad%20%20*%2Che%20shrugged%20his%20shoulders%2Cshrugged%20his%20shoulder&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20his%20heavy%20shoulders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20his%20great%20shoulders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20his%20thin%20shoulders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20his%20broad%20shoulders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20shrugged%20his%20shoulders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20his%20shoulder%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20his%20heavy%20shoulders%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20his%20great%20shoulders%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20his%20thin%20shoulders%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20his%20broad%20shoulders%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20shrugged%20his%20shoulders%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cshrugged%20his%20shoulder%3B%2Cc1) I added the terms: *shrugged his heavy* *, *shrugged his great* *, *shrugged his thin* *, *he shrugged his broad* *, *he shrugged his shoulders*, and *shrugged his shoulder*. Once again the asterisk substitutes the first word that follows

[image]

Men only shrug their great or massive *shoulders*, I was hoping for something a little more titillating. You may have noticed that I forgot to add *he shrugged his massive* * but if you don't believe men have massive shoulders, do the operation yourselves...

Oh, all right. I'll do it myself

[image]

Unsurprisingly, the adjective *broad* is most commonly associated with male shoulders, but what I do find peculiar is the drop in the number of times *men  shrug their shoulders* (see the penultimate chart), apparently there was an impressive peak in the 1930s followed by a steady decline.  I wonder why?

---

> Is there anything else that can be shrugged, besides shoulders?

### Yes! You can also shrug these things off

I Googled *"shrugged off the"* in Google Books and found...

> [**shrugged off the**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22shrugged%20off%20the%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) *news, leaflets, meaning of, notion, denial,
>   sand, role, injury, idea*, ***arm***, *past, loss, signals,
>   irritation, annoying sth, blazer, Nazi's, thought, problems, crazy
>   things, worry, traps, overcoat, indifference, eerie sensation,
>   backpack, criticism, belt, ugly memory, prospect, nervousness, crash,
>   police assault, comments, comparisons, feelings of guilt, yoke,
>   gratitude, efforts, question, bad news, phenomenon, complaints,
>   **fraternal hand**, encounter, feeling of impending doom, report, deal, treason accusation, feeling in disbelief, dream, coat, lifelong
>   sacrifice, offending limb, snide remark, London damp, incident,
>   possibility, knapsack*, ***man's hands***, *fact, cool chill, shawl,
>   gloomy mood, frontier town mentality, pain, daily calls, feeling of
>   apprehension, suggestion, analysis, prudish atmosphere, stories, 
>   feeling of being watched, threat, blouse, burden, suit jacket, apathy,
>   pack, horrendous accident, wealth and power, results, girl's embrace,
>   punishment, consequences, hood of the anorak, cold, self-pity, first
>   signs of, advice, doubters and the snipers, slight, pressure*,
>   ***hands that attempted to grab him***, *accoutrements of their past, stigma, snub, environmental costs,  cares of the world, attacks,
>   charge, tendency, first frost, abuse, compliment, request, hurt,
>   negativity, blankets, effects of the weed, wasted emotion*, ***guy's
>   hand***, *darkness, failure; Chinese, the Mongols, and Siamese; mantle
>   of religion, thefts, warnings, whole business, economic and social
>   problems, letter, old man, reprimand, critique,  shackles of
>   traditional morality, lack of popularity, blows, conflict, cape,
>   announcement, yellow jacket, duty, camisole of Marxism, tremor of
>   excitement, sleaziness swirling about him, stick as he had shrugged
>   off the carrot.; deepening suspicion, happy memory of that episode,*
>   etc...

I stopped at page forty, but as you can see there are many other things besides shoulders which can be *shrugged off*, and one of them being *hands*.

Comment: Great revival of a three-year old question. Love the detail.

Comment: `I wonder why?` -- they probably grew [eyebrows](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-hrzpYNHTfAM/UMi4LtQvOEI/AAAAAAAAASo/unSWTYSbK8c/s1600/bushy+eyebrows.gif) and are now shrugging these!

Comment: Like the first half, but for the second: " I'm aware of constructs like "He shrugged it off." but that's not what I'm interested in, "

Comment: @TimLymington I'm sorry, but could you clarify a little more. Like as in "I like" or "as" and I don't understand the point you're making with *but for the second*. Sorry, if I sound dim. Note, that this answer was written last year.

Comment: Sorry I was too elliptical. The first half of the answer is good enough to upvote, but the hard work you put into investigating *shrugged off* is something OP explicitly did not want.

Comment: @TimLymington but I also showed that a person can literally, and not metaphorically, *shrug somebody's hand off*. So, in a roundabout way, it is connected to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does and as far as shrug is performed by lifting both shoulders up, so i think there's no need to say shoulders.

Also, [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=He%20shrugged,%20He%20shrugged%20his%20shoulders&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that the usage without "shoulder" is more common.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we say this man is shrugging his hands, even if he does not move his shoulders when he does it...

[image: shrug]