# "Gnashing teeth" - why only teeth?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Why is it always "gnash one's teeth"?  Is anything else ever gnashed?

Comment: I'd be curious what else you'd consider gnashing.

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26439/can-shrugging-only-be-done-with-shoulders

Comment: More related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10614/is-there-a-term-for-words-that-have-a-single-meaning-or-are-only-used-in-a-singl (stormy petrels). The linked [list](http://www.satiche.org.uk/satiche/sat-0342.htm) contains "The only thing you can GNASH is YOUR TEETH"

Answer (score 5):

The word "gnash" is specifically used only in terms of the teeth.

From Dictionary.com:

verb (used with object)

1. to grind or strike (the teeth) together, especially in rage or pain.
2. to bite with grinding teeth.

verb (used without object)

1. to gnash the teeth.

From my experience, I don't think this term can be utilised in any other fashion. Additionally, I have never seen it used another way. It is likely a term that evolved specifically to describe the action. It is also possibly onomatopoeia for the sound of teeth grinding together or the vocalised noise one sometimes makes while performing the action.

Comment: OED does have an example with jagged ice floes gnashing.  But even then presumably because they are like teeth.

Comment: Ah, yes, I had forgotten about the OED, thanks for the reminder. I'll check that out later.

Comment: In its etymology of _gnash_, MW notes "probably of imitative origin," so your speculation about gnash being onomatopoeic is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard it used in relation to gearboxes in cars, for example a person not used to driving with a clutch might 'gnash the gears' while changing.

Comment: Of course, the gears have teeth...

Comment: In general, it's used where a biting or chewing motion is implied in a destructive sense. I've heard people use it when referencing gears, wood chippers, shredders, etc.