# Any English phrase whose words appear nowhere else?

Tags: phrases, idioms, archaicisms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a term for words that have a single meaning or are only used in a single context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10614/is-there-a-term-for-words-that-have-a-single-meaning-or-are-only-used-in-a-singl)

I want to find some English phrases whose individual words are seldom used outside of that phrase. That way its words show up in the phrase alone, but nowhere else.

Comment: http://ask.metafilter.com/154021/Obscure-words-combine-to-form-common-phrase

Comment: That seems a reasonable list. The question is [off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) here.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That list does have a lot of false positives, meaning that it claims words are unique to those phrases which in fact are not. In fact, apart from perhaps *fro*, the rest are hardly unknown in outside contexts.

Comment: Yes, but there is a [reasonable list there](http://ask.metafilter.com/154021/Obscure-words-combine-to-form-common-phrase#2208175), with some more below that. Any word *can* be used on its own, so the question is likely to be unanswerable; although I could be fairly confident *petard* is very rarely found without some form of *hoist*.

Comment: They're called [stormy petrels](http://www.kith.org/logos/words/lower/c.html) and there's [a long list](http://www.kith.org/logos/words/lower/petrels.html).

Comment: I'm more used to the term **cranberry expression**. There's an article with a good analysis at http://homepage.univie.ac.at/beata.trawinski/presentations/lrec-mwe_08.pdf . Also, at http://www.docstoc.com/docs/123195596/Fixed-Expressions-and-Idioms-in-English-A-Corpus-Based-Approach , Moon deals with 'cranberry collocations' as a subset of 'fixed expressions and [sic] idioms' (section 5.1.3) . Note, however, that a **cranberry word** (like _cranberry_) is usually taken to be a 'false compound', which, unlike 'teapot', could not have been formed from a combination of two words (no word 'cran').

Comment: @AndrewLeach I disagree: words like *trials, tribulations, cease, desist, wreak, havoc, moot, plethora* and most of the others all enjoy a perfectly healthy solitary existence.

Comment: @Mitch Again, even that isn't quite right.  For example, certainly there can and have been delphic pronouncements without mentioning augury or oracles.

Comment: @tchrist: What else than havoc is ever being wreaked nowadays?

Comment: @SF. Ruin, for one.  And havoc also gets cried.

Comment: @tchrist: Are you disagreeing with my suggestion of 'stormy petrel' or with one example in that list?

Comment: @tchrist: roughly 1:2000 frequency ratio in ngram, Google has a total of 180 unique results for "wreak ruin", but I concede. This is a valid option.

Comment: We could argue about any of the suggestions in that list, but part of that argument is semantics – how "seldom" is "seldom used"? At any rate, any of the phrases in the list can be checked using Ngrams, such as [this one](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wreak+havoc%2Cwreak&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) for _(wreak) havoc_ and [this one](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moral+turpitude%2Cturpitude&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) for _(moral) turpitude_. Whether or not a given candidate "passes" the test would be subjective.

Answer (score 0):

How about "to boot," in the sense of "in addition" in occasionally used phrases like "... and I'll throw this in to boot?" In American English the only other use of the word, which is an Anglo Saxon word meaning profit or advantage, not the French word for shoe, is in reference to an additional amount needed to complete a tax free exchange of real property.

Comment: Booty comes to mind.