# British Mass Nouns versus American Count Nouns

Tags: american-english, british-english, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, transatlantic-differences

British English often employs *mass nouns* where American English would only employ *count nouns*. Count nouns are nouns which take pluralization and numerical quantifiers like 'many'. Mass nouns can't be pluralized and take volume quantifiers like 'a bit of'. For example:

1. I like sport.
2. I like drink.
3. I pay tax.
4. I've got toothache/earache/stomachache/backache.
5. I eat mashed potato/scrambled egg.
6. I play with lego.

In American English, we would render these:

1. I like sports.
2. I like to drink / I like to have drinks.
3. I pay taxes.
4. I've got a toothache/earache/stomachache/backache.
5. I eat mashed potatoes/scrambled eggs.
6. I play with legos.

These facts are documented [here](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2006/07/countmass-nouns-potato-egg-tax-sport.html), [here](http://northgare.net/blog/2004/07/eggs_and_sports/) and [here](http://www.myenglishteacher.eu/question/some-nouns-are-uncountable-but-some-of-these-nouns-differ-from-english-to-american-would-you-please-help-me-in-this-field-thanks-a-lot/). But this difference is not mentioned on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English) page comparing British English to American English.

My question is simply what other nouns which are standardly count in AmE are often mass in BrE?

Further, are there any *broad categories* of nouns (for example, food nouns) that tend to be count in AmE but tend to be mass in BrE? Or does the difference only exist for particular and isolated lexical items? (The first link I provided says that many foods are not conventionally massified in BrE, for example 'refried bean').

Here are two final caveats:

First, I know that any count noun can be turned into a mass noun by simply putting it in the syntactic position of a mass noun. That's why "I ate (a bit of) chicken" is acceptable in both AmE and BrE. But I am asking about the obvious differences between AmE and BrE regards their *conventional uses* of nouns as mass and count.

Second, I know these types of list questions are hard for single users to answer, and sometimes generate controversy on EL&U (for example, [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327825/modern-english-kennings) on kennings generated some controvery). Still, I'll upvote any responses that make a novel contribution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40898/discussion-on-question-by-silenus-british-mass-nouns-versus-american-count-nouns).

Comment: British/Australian/etc.: My favourite subject is maths. American: My favorite subject is math.

Comment: This over-simplifies the issue/s. It is moot whether 'sports' is plural-form non-count or plural count in 'I like sports', but 'brains' certainly isn't count in 'In this kind of work, brains are less important than guts.' and 'It doesn’t take much brains to figure this out.' [[Lasersohn](https://semanticsarchive.net/Archive/DdkZDc0N/massandplural.pdf)] And the indefinite article does not guarantee a count usage: 'She took a pride in her appearance' / *'They took several prides in ...'. // Also, 'count (etc) usages' should be discussed; the string 'count nouns' obscures the truth that many ...

Comment: (I've seen it claimed _most_) nouns have both count and non-count usages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mighty Fine Words and Smashing Expressions: Making Sense of Transatlantic English (2001)](https://books.google.com/books?id=dUTdk93cq9UC&pg=PA37&dq=british+mass+nouns&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ-PuMloDOAhVkwYMKHfY7B3UQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Summary of this book's section on BrE/AmE uncountable/countable nouns:

- Most vegetables that are uncountable in BrE are countable in AmE, with these exceptions:
  *broccoli, spinach, lettuce*, i.e. vegetables that already have different ways of distinguishing discrete forms: *head of broccoli, leaf of spinach, lettuce leaf*
- Individual servings of coffee/tea are countable in BrE, e.g. *a coffee/a tea*, while in AmE you would say *a cup of coffee/a cup of tea*.
- *accomodation* is uncountable in BrE, while *accomodations* in AmE refers to the multiple different types of accomodation: room and board, food, entertainment
- various different *aches* are uncountable in BrE, and countable in AmE, such as "she's got cramps" (for menstrual distress but used for muscle cramps as well).
- BrE attaches plural verbs to group nouns and organizations, e.g. "the team are playing"
- *(circle-making) [compass](http://www.wpclipart.com/education/geometry/geometric_drawing/compass_draw_circle_5.png), (conduit) [main](http://comps.canstockphoto.com/can-stock-photo_csp6575832.jpg), (business) [overhead](https://s3.amazonaws.com/lowres.cartoonstock.com/business-commerce-profit-chart-overhead-businesses-business_models-lfin209_low.jpg), and (weighing) [scale](http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/yTo/gRA/yTogRA7bc.jpeg)* are usually used in their singular form in AmE and in plural form in BrE, while BrE usually uses *wood* to refer to a small forest and AmE uses *woods*.

[image]

---

In BrE, *flies* is acceptable to refer to your trousers' zipper:

[image]
http://fandom-grammar.livejournal.com/106339.html

---

BrE: roadworks [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/roadworks?q=roadwork)

AmE: roadwork [MacMillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/roadwork)

---

BrE: "a saving of 10%"

AmE: "a savings of 10%"

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64918/a-savings-is-that-even-grammatical

---

Comment: Interesting piece, I think it would be useful if you added some comments on your finding.

Comment: I upvoted for *accommodation*; the observation regarding ingredients like *carrot*; and the observation regarding *coffee* (here, the transatlantic mass/count pattern is reversed); the other number differences from *compass* through *woods* is also very interesting. But I agree with @Josh61 that a better answer would have a bit of commentary, or at least a summary of the new findings (since a lot of what's in this passage was already mentioned in my question).

Comment: ok, I added a summary. Feel free to edit my answer for anything else.

Comment: In BrE, *compass* (singular) refers to a device that point North. BrE uses both *woods* and *woods* [If you go down to the woods today, ...](http://ingeb.org/songs/ifyougod.html). As a Brit, I would say "she's got **cramp**" (singular). We would also be equally happy with *either* form of "the team is/are playing".

Comment: Is it really preferably in BrE to say “I have headache”? That sounds as utterly bizarre in my inner voice in BrE as it does in AmE. “I’ve got cramp” just about passes (though I’d use the plural more naturally), and “I’ve got toothache/stomach-ache” both sound reasonably all right either way… but “I’ve got headache”?!?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet 1. I've never heard “I have headache”. Why do you think we say that? Most people would say “I have a headache” or “I've got a headache”. 2. We might alternatively say "I’ve got the cramps" [plural]. 3. "I've got toothache" -yes: an ache in one tooth! 4. "I’ve got stomach-ache" = an ache in my stomach!

Comment: @V0ight In BrE, we don't use "flies ... to refer to [our] pants zipper": we use it to refer to the zipper in our *trousers*. We wear our *[under]pants* underneath our trousers (as is apparent from the quotation you've given)! ;-) Incidentally, they used to be called "fly buttons" before we used zips - what were "fly buttons" called in the US?

Comment: @TrevorD Well, I don't think people say that, but the book quoted from in this answer (and the site quoted from in the question) says they do. I've never heard anyone say they “have headache” either, but I would be surprised if the book just took it from out of thin air.

Comment: @TrevorD ~ my mistake, I didn't know that *pants* referred to underpants

Comment: @V0ight You quote AmE as using "a savings of 10%". Is that correct: "a" is singular & "saving**s**" is plural!

Comment: @TrevorD ~ yep, that's how we say it over here :D

Comment: @V0ight I've taken the liberty of making 2 clarifications: 1. added date of book (i thought it's appearance was much older than it is.) 2. Clarified meaning of "cramps" - I had thought it was a ref. to mussel cramp, typically in the legs, and my earlier comments referred to that meaning.

Comment: @TrevorD ~ no problem. And *cramps* can refer to muscle cramps as well in AmE, but yes in the specific example in the book it was referring to menstrual cramps

Comment: @TrevorD, fly buttons are typically called a *button fly* in AmE, as in: "Sadly these jeans don't have a zipper, but rather a button fly.

Answer (score 0):

Another is BrE mass *surgery*, and countable *operation* for the individual item, and AmE countable *surgery*.