# British English plural verb for group noun in a contraction

Tags: british-english, verb-agreement, contractions

I'm curious about the use of the famous British plural verb form with a group noun¹ *in a contraction*. The general custom for the plural is discussed [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331377/british-mass-nouns-versus-american-count-nouns) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76448/pronouns-for-collective-nouns-british-and-american) but those don't call out contractions.

England football fans [are currently singing the following](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-44711734) to the tune of *September* by Earth, Wind, and Fire:

> Woah, England are in Russia,
>   
> Woah, drinking all your vodka,
>   
> Woah, England's going all the way!

Now, it's a football song, not high poetry, but note that in the above, the first line uses ***England are*** but the last line uses ***England's***. Unless we magically decide that the first England is the team but the second England is the country, that's...interesting.

The plural contraction is really awkward:

- England're going all the way
- Family're hard work sometimes
- The group're on it

...and as we know, awkwardness tends to get smoothed out of language.<sup>[citation needed] ;-)</sup>

Is this just a fudge to make the song's meter work? Or is it a deeper pattern to use the singular form in a contraction even when using the plural form otherwise, perhaps because of the awkwardness?

Sadly Google Ngrams won't let me look for *England is going vs. England are going* (and *England is vs. England are* is too general) and in any case, I'd be flooded with American English results. Trying to search [Hansard](https://api.parliament.uk/historic-hansard/index.html), unfortunately Google Search treats the `'` as a space.

I can't use my own instinct on this and am having trouble coming up with other examples to look for: I'm an English/American dual national who spent 30 years growing up in the U.S. reading British novels and watching British television on PBS, who's been back in the UK for 18 years. So my dialect is mid-Atlantic and horribly confused. :-)

---

¹ E.g. *the team **are*** vs. American English's *the team **is*** for nouns representing groups of people (roughly; there's lots of nuance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a fudge to make the meter work.

Answer (score 2):

"England **are** in Russia," because the "guys from England" are in Russia, not the country.

"**England's** going all the way" because the team (England) is, not the members individually.

Comment: Thanks, but any citations that could strengthen this? To me it's tortured. I'm having no trouble finding "England are going all the way" not as a contraction ([here](https://www.msn.com/fr-ca/divertissement/celebrite/fearless-england-going-all-the-way/vi-AAcfRLQ), [here](https://twitter.com/amirkingkhan/status/1010908297799626752?lang=en), [here](https://www.thesun.co.uk/world-cup-2018/6615353/roy-keane-pundits-stitches-blasts-england-panama-gareth-southgate-complacency/), [here](https://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/international/10351666.html)).

Comment: I can also found counter examples to my examples above ([here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-5915225/England-fans-erupt-rapture-team-FINALLY-wins-World-Cup-penalty-shootout.html), [here](https://infosurhoy.com/cocoon/saii/xhtml/en_GB/news/world-cup-2018-pickford-helps-england-beat-colombia-in-penalties/)), but that's the problem, the American form is increasingly prevalent even on this side of the pond, making searches a hard way to evaluate this. But in general, again, Br.Eng. treats groups *of people* as plurals, whether they're "in Russia" or "going all the way," most of the time.

Comment: I am looking at it as more of a semantic thing than a syntactic one. Those sentences seem most logical and so most natural.

Comment: Are you a native speaker of British English? Again, in general "England are..." ("the team are", "the family are") is standard here (though again, there's nuance). Sounds like you're a native speaker of American English...?

Comment: *(OMG, can't believe the typo "...can also found..." made it into my comment above. I guess Skitt's law applies on ELU even when one* isn't *correcting someone else's grammar... :-) )*

Answer (score 0):

I think it's one team but many fans.
In the first line, the fans could be singing about themselves:

"We **are** England. We **are** in Russia. Ergo, England **are** in Russia".

The second line backs that up. I hope the English *players* weren't drinking all the vodka, so it must refer to the fans.

The third line refers to the team, hence singular.

That said, contractions in song lyrics tend to be ...ahem... *imaginative* and made to fit the rhythm/meter of the song rather than any precedent or proper grammar. I might reference ["Hark the Herald Angels Sing"](https://library.timelesstruths.org/music/Hark_the_Herald_Angels_Sing/) as an example where vowels are, somewhat, discarded (in some versions).

Answer (score -1):

I am Canadian and our school taught that: Nouns like team, group, family, class etc are a singular entity and were therefore treated as such. However I watch some British television and they repeatedly say things like "The team were riding on their new bus" rather than "The team was riding on it's new bus." Of course this is easily resolved by adding the word "members" to team. I always thought that Canada taught "proper" English so it is hard to get used to this.