# When two words produce a distinct meaning

Tags: meaning, pronunciation, compounds

I've thought about how we say "bad guy", when we refer to a character in a game or a story, with a different cadence than we say "bad guy", when we mean "a guy who is bad".

"Bad guy" in the former sense is almost its own word, with its own meaning and pronunciation.

Possible other examples:

```
Hot dog
Black belt
Lazy eye
Green card
```

Is there a term for this phenomenon? If I could describe it, it's when two words become a unit as opposed to discrete words.

Comment: Better examples might be "a red light", "a green house" etc. "a hot dog" is good.

Comment: French has *les propres mains,* and *les main propres* (one means clean hands, the other ones own hands, where one is conventional and the specific. But I don't know a name for that either.

Comment: @Cascabel I added better examples

Comment: There are separate issues involved here. One is compounding, where the compound may take on a narrower or even different definition from the simplex words (a _black bird_ is a (any) bird that is black,  whereas a blackbird is (normally) a specimen of Turdus merula (so a blackbird may be brown). On the other hand, a blackboard _is_ a board that is black (but was once usually used for writing on). // The other issue is intersectiveness, and non-semantically-predicative adjectives, which occur other than with compounding. For example, a heavy smoker is not a smoker who is heavy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [modern English kennings](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327825/modern-english-kennings) On intersectiveness: [term for things like 'naughty step' where the step is not what is naughty](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104700/term-for-things-like-naughty-step-where-the-step-is-not-what-is-naughty).

Comment: I don't think that dupe works in this case...

Comment: @Cascabel 'hot dog' is a perfect example of what's discussed (and intended by OP there: 'a compound consisting of two nouns [though sometimes adjective + noun] whose semantic relationship yields, indirectly, a nominal that is not a synonym for either of them, though one of them might be a metonym for part of the idea') at 'modern English kennings'; whether the title needs amending is a different matter.  // 'Guinea pig' would _additionally? however?_ be a _misnomer_. // Stress patterns and compounding dealt with elsewhere.

Comment: "Stress patterns and compounding dealt with elsewhere." I think that is the point of the Q...

Comment: Yes, it's all about stress and rhythm. As [Henry Lee Smith](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Henry+Lee+Smith%22) used to say, _Not every white house is the White House_.

Comment: Frankly?  The bad guy example is terrible. There are not two meanings. What is the matter with everyone?? Sometimes people around here blow my mind.

Comment: Why does Robin Hood have different emphasis in his name than everyone else?

Comment: Is polysemy just too broad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"... with a different *cadence* [...] **with its own meaning and pronunciation."** -[OP](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/417700/lua)

I am interpreting that to mean [stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)), or intonation.

In speech, [Compounds](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/nouns-compound-nouns) are indicated by putting the ***stress*** on the ***first*** word. A simple adjective + noun collocation has the stress on the *second* word.

For example,

> "go left at the 'white house'"

...may have 2 or more interpretations when you are riding  down Pennsylvania avenue in Washington and talking to your driver.

---

For lack of a better term (at the moment), I would call it "***contrastive patterns***". Possibly it is a type of ["minimal pairs"](https://www.cambridge.org/us/cambridgeenglish/catalog/grammar-vocabulary-and-pronunciation/ship-or-sheep-3rd-edition).

This is a form of "coding", which in this case means the compound noun  is expected to be understood by the position of the stress. This type of production  can be a source of confusion for many non-native speakers as it depends upon the de-coding of the pronunciation. Sometimes there is an L1-L2 confusion.

> ...such  ***contrastive  patterns***  as ˈHOT ˌdog(type  of  food)  [compound]  vs. ˌhot ˈDOG(hot  canine)[phrase]”and “a ˈGREEN ˌhouse(a building made of glass for growing plants inside) [compound] vs. a ˌgreen ˈHOUSE(a house  which  is  painted  green)  [phrase]the  difference  in  the  stress  placement  is  a  clear  indication  of  meaning  changes expressed.Compounds have primary stress on the first word and on those following them they have secondary stress. In the compound ˈGOLF ˌball,  the  first  word  has  primary  stress  and  the  following  the  secondary  stress.As  for  phrases,  however, their  qualified  elements  i.e.  the  words  second  in  line  are  stressed  more  prominently

[Stress Placement on Compounds and Phrases in English (PhD. Metin YurtbaşıBayburt)](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED580168.pdf)

Spoken compounds are easily understood by native speakers, but often mis-understood by non-native speakers. This is considered a high-level topic for EFL/ESL students studying at call-centers.

Comment: This is in fact used in a children's riddle: "if the red house is on the corner, and the yellow house is next to it, where is the white house?" The answer is: "The White House is in Washington D.C." (with the two instances of "the white house" being stressed differently.)

Answer (score 2):

**[Compound Word](https://allesl.com/compound-words-examples-open-closed-hyphenated/)**

There are three types of compound words:

- open (with a space between, as in your examples)
- closed (as in "grandmother")
- hyphenated (as in "high-speed")

You are referring to open compound words.